# GWT Spell Check

Tags: firefox, gwt, spell-checking

I would like to implement a "spell check" for my GWT rich text area.  I do understand that Firefox and other browsers automatically highlight words with misspellings, but I need to be able to warn the user before they submit a form that there are potential misspellings if they ignore the "squiggles".

Is it possible to use a javascript call to see if the default Firefox spell checker has detected errors?  I could use that to stop the form from being submitted with misspellings.

Any thoughts out there?

Thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you cannot guarantee that your user is using Firefox (or a browser that has spellcheck).  Secondly, I do not believe that you can access most browser-level components from your JavaScript code.

You can find spellcheck libraries and call them accordingly.  See [SpellCheck.java](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/branches/opt_imgs_and_startup/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/richtext/SpellCheck.java?spec=svn675&r=675) as a starting point, but I'm sure there are many more.

Comment: Thank you for your response!  I also found SpellCheck.java but it's not compatible with the latest versions of GWT.  This is a webapp locked down with Firefox at a customer site (so no true requirement for cross-browser functionality. Yes, I understand that's bad, but a reality.)

Comment: You can still (1) use any JavaScript spell check library and invoke it using JSNI, or you can (2) find a Java spell check library and add it to your GWT module, and if that still doesn't work, you can (3) find a Java spell check library and add it on the server-side, invoking it via a GWT RPC call.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan!  I was hoping for an out of the box solution, thanks for the confirmation that this might not be the case!  I'll post back here with the solution I chose and why.